# How to list all parameters passed to an RDLC for debugging?

Tags: rdlc

The software KWHotel uses RDLCs to create many of its invoices, booking confirmations, and reports. I would like to know how to create an RDLC that outputs all parameters passed to it so I can identify what information is available for creating RDLCs.

Comment: To clarify, I have no control over the application code itself. I only have control over the XML contents of the RDLC files so this is where I am focusing my efforts.

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to achieve here but you can tell what the parameters are if they havea  similar format  like this: `Parameters!paramName.Value`  I guess you could look for all the unique variations of `Parameters!%.Value` in the file to give you a list.